# Altering return value of Varchar2 form default(4000) to (10char)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

My Question is:

```
create function jbmdate (p_date in varchar2)
return varchar2
as
begin
  return to_char(to_date(p_date,'YYYYMMDD'),'DD.MM.YYYY');
end;
```

As you see this returns a varchar with default value : 4000 byte/char.

But the Problem is that it will be used within a GUI so 4000 is quit unlucky big.

So how could i possible change the return value of this varchar2 to (10 char)?

[image: View of Gui Table altered]

It should look like this

but i looks like this when used in the gui.

[image: View of Gui Table]

So the real problem is not the gui itself but the sql ... shown here in squirrle sql: 
[image: View of SQuirrle Table]

So how can i alter the Precision which is returned by the function.

Comment: The function will never return more than 8 characters, not 4000. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: So this function will be used in a gui where it shows you a table : DATE - TIME : But the value of this table is varchar 2 default . So there is the date like 20.20.2020 but shown like 20.20.2020.......................................................................   (.....excluded for showing as an example)

Comment: I´ve edited my Question with an Image for getting a better idea of what i mean.

Comment: varchar only stores as many characters as the length of a string and not how long a string can be. Varchar2 (4000) means that you can store 4000 characters, but if you only store a string with 8 characters, it's only 8 and not 4000. Or is your column char type?

Comment: if your output for some reason is `20.20.2020.........................` (which is not visible in your uploaded image by the way) then the problem resides somewhere else and not in the function. As @hotfix mentioned your function returns only 10 characters.

Comment: Try with trim function.

Comment: Ive edited again. I hope now it´s more clear.

Comment: @ThomasMattmüller In GUI, what is the datatype?

Comment: I´m so sorry for the bad questioning. :x    But yeah edited it again.

Comment: Output format of date values should be driven by your GUI/Client application and/or current user session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` settings rather than hard-coded by you.Why on earth do you store date values as number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52712/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create function jbmdate (p_date in varchar2)
return varchar2
as
begin
  return to_char(to_date(p_date,'YYYYMMDD'),'DD.MM.YYYY');
end;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT '20180818' AS input,
       jbmdate( '20180818' ) AS dt,
       DUMP( jbmdate( '20180818' ) ) AS "dump"
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52712/2/0)**:

```
|    INPUT |         DT |                                        dump |
|----------|------------|---------------------------------------------|
| 20180818 | 18.08.2018 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,56,46,48,56,46,50,48,49,56 |
```

As you can see from the output of the `DUMP()` function, the returned `VARCHAR2` data type has a length of 10. Wherever your 3990 extra bytes are coming from it is not being generated by SQL or PL/SQL and you should look further downstream in the application that is querying the database.

**Query 2**: If you want to explicitly cast the `VARCHAR2` to a specific length then you can use the `CAST( your_value AS VARCHAR2(10) )` function to cast it to a length of 10 but, as you can see below, it does not affect the output from `DUMP` as the returned value already had a length of 10.

```
SELECT '20180818' AS input,
       CAST( jbmdate( '20180818' ) AS VARCHAR2(10) ) AS dt,
       DUMP( CAST( jbmdate( '20180818' ) AS VARCHAR2(10) ) ) AS "dump"
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52712/2/1)**:

```
|    INPUT |         DT |                                        dump |
|----------|------------|---------------------------------------------|
| 20180818 | 18.08.2018 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,56,46,48,56,46,50,48,49,56 |
```

Comment: So , our Framework/Application/Gui works with the Precision which, shown already, is returned as 4000 as it is the default. Thats because the function returns varchar2 -> default.... You can trim, cast it, or whatever but it wont do anything with the outcome of varchar2.    create function jbmdate (p_date in varchar2)
return varchar2 // this will be returned everytime whatever will be done to the procedure down here . So if i alter the code after "AS", its meaningless-> a default varchar2 will be returned. //
as
begin
  return to_char(to_date(p_date,'YYYYMMDD'),'DD.MM.YYYY');
end;

Comment: @ThomasMattmüller Then either look for a way to override your framework's default handling of precision so that you can specify the actual precision or try wrapping the function call using `CAST` to specify the precision after the function has returned. So from your picture, the query would be `select CAST( jbmdate( orhjobdt ) AS VARCHAR2(10) ) AS jobdatum, CAST( jbmtime( orhjobtm ) AS VARCHAR2(10) ) AS jobziet FROM ...` which is what I did in Query 2 of my answer.

Comment: I tryd your cast select. Now it is as i wanted it to happen. Precision is 10. So can i eventually put this in the function somehow ? I´m clearly not an expert into sql or database itself.

Comment: @ThomasMattmüller Try it and see. Just change the return line to be wrapped in a cast like `return CAST( to_char(to_date(p_date,'YYYYMMDD'),'DD.MM.YYYY') AS VARCHAR2(10) );` I do not have your Framework to test so do not know whether you will need to do it outside the function or whether inside will be sufficient and you can find out much quicker than I can.

Comment: I will. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

A function only defines the base type of its return value (in this case, `VARCHAR2`). It can't define a more specific length to influence the display format used by your GUI.

Applications will vary in the way they display strings. For example, PL/SQL Developer will display the output in the compact form you are expecting, and so will [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com).

> It should look like this
>   ...
>   but it looks like this when used in the gui.
>   ...
>   So the real problem is not the gui itself but the sql

I can't see how you reached that conclusion, as it seems clear that the issue is in the GUI (SQuirreL SQL Client?) Perhaps you could try it in a different tool.

Comment: I came to conclusion by checking it in some other different tool! Whatever i will alter in  "to_char(to_date(p_date,'YYYYMMDD'),'DD.MM.YYYY');" it wont´t be bothered by the source -> everytime "return varchar2," will be the value which is beeing returned and with the default value of varchar2 -> 4000 byte/char. I´ll need to handle this... nothing else and there is my problem ... With none googling i came to an result which were satisfying.

Comment: @ThomasMattmüller your Framework/Application/Gui  is CASTING results or show you false information; in PL/SQL a varchar2 variable can be defined to any lenght from 1 to 32767 bytes and in Oracle DBMS for tables is from 1 to 4000 bytes; storage is up to the current length of string there in no right padding; what is your Framework/Application/Gui, what is the other tool?